# Sharepoint Custom Color overlay is not showing for users of that Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, overlay

I followed [this guide](https://www.spsimply.com/home/2018/6/2/sharepoint-customize-the-colors-for-calendar-overlays) to customizing my sharepoint calendar overlays.

However upon sharing the Sharepoint with the Team, the custom colors are only showing for me and not the other Team members.

*Would anyone happen to know why that is and how to fix it?
Thanks*

Comment: Where you have added the CSS file? Do other users have access to it?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that the CSS file you uploaded is either checked out to you (never been checked in) or other team members don't have access to it. To check that, have one of the team members who can't see the colors launch developer tools, open the network tab, refresh the page, and check for `"401 Not Found"` or `"403 Forbidden"` responses.